# How can I restart a list of runnables automatically after execution, in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a `List` of runnables, returned by a service. These runnables are being scheduled at a fix rate, with a delay of one minute. The code looks as follows:

```
public class Migrator {

// Define one minute in milliseconds.
private static final long INITIAL_DELAY = 60000;
private static final long UPDATE_RATE = 60000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    Set<String> dbNames = getDbNames();
    dbNames.forEach(db -> {
        List<Runnable> runnableList = new MigrationTaskManager(db).getRunnableTasksForDB();
        runnableList.forEach(runnable -> {
            executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, INITIAL_DELAY, UPDATE_RATE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        });
    });
 }
}
```

Upon execution, it works as expected, and executes the runnables every minute, as follows:
[image]

Is there any way I can make these `runnables` re-start automatically after they finish executing (regardless of the execution time they take), instead of having to use `executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, INITIAL_DELAY, UPDATE_RATE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`? I could really use some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command,
                                                 long initialDelay,
                                                 long delay,
                                                 TimeUnit unit);
```

This method where you can input a delay, restarts runnable after the execution is finished + delay. So just put a delay 0 and that solves your problem:

```
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 1, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

Comment: using a delay value of 0 threw an IllegalArgumentException. But, I suppose all the runnables will restart automatically after the execution, followed by the delay, if any passed?

Comment: oh yes you are right it is not allowed to be 0, you have to specify at least one -> updated the answer